# Copying over part of a table from SQL Server to Aurora DB (Based on MySQL by AWS)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-aurora

I have a legacy SQL Server DB and I need to copy part of a very very big table on it over to a new Aurora DB cluster from AWS (RDS).

The old table in SQL server has 1.8 billion records and 43 columns, however in the new DB I will only have 13 of those columns carried over and almost all rows.

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on the best way that I can move this data across?

I wrote a simple Python script to query the SQL server and then execute insert statements on the new DB but I estimate this would take about 30 hours to run after I did some tests on smaller sets of data.

Any ideas?

P.S Aurora is based off of MySQL so I would imagine if it works for MySQL it would work for Aurora.

Comment: Be sure not to create any indexes, except PK, before import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can get the data you want into something like a CSV file, `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` should be pretty performant.

I did wonder whether it would be allowed on RDS and discovered an AWS article on [importing data into MySQL on RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html). I couldn't find an equivalent one for Aurora, only [migrating from an RDS based MySQL instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Migrate.html). There's an [Amazon RDS for Aurora Export/Import Performance Best Practices](https://d0.awsstatic.com/product-marketing/Aurora/Aurora_Export_Import_Best_Practices_v1-3.pdf) document that has one reference to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, however.